# Real world Spring. Do you really inject primitive values via bean definition?

Tags: java, spring

The following seems making sense if we consider the attributes are constant.

```
<bean id="student" class="com.Student">
    <property name="name" value="Paul"/>
    <property name="id" value="12"/>
</bean>
```

---

```
Object s = fac.getBean("student");
Student stu = (Student) s;
```

Probably the most dynamic way would be :

```
<bean id="student" class="com.Student"/>
```

---

```
Object s = fac.getBean("student");
Student stu = (Student) s;
stu.setName(...);
stu.setId(..);
```

My question is that, is this just way to introduce the basic mechanism of Spring framework or you really do primitive values injection.

Comment: In my opinion, that's just an example of DI in Spring. In the real world, if anything, the value would be stated in a config file and the property value would contain `${key}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine scenario:

```
<beans profile="development">
 <bean id="student" class="com.Student">
    <property name="name" value="${name}"/>
    <property name="id" value="123"/>
 </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
 <bean id="student" class="com.Student">
    <property name="name" value="${name}"/>
    <property name="id" value="#{idProvider.getId()}"/>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

now you would have 2 different property files...

development.properties

```
 name=developer
```

production.properties

```
 name=Paul
```

To do it your way you would need 2 versions of code.

Comment: You right I forget that those values can be also assigned dynamically via EL. I give you upvote